# PyTorch TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

Tags: python, pytorch

I am writing a CNN with `PyTorch` using my custom dataset consisting of 10 classes. Here is my code:

```
import random
model.eval()
randomIndex = random.randint(0, len(dataset_val) - 1)
test = dataset_val[randomIndex]
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
labels = ["5","10","20","30","40","50","75","100","150","200"]
def show_data(data_sample, size):
   plt.imshow(data_sample[0].numpy().reshape(size,size), cmap='gray')
   plt.title(f"Real Label = {labels[data_sample[0]]}")
for n,data_sample in enumerate(dataset):
   show_data(data_sample, IMAGE_SIZE)
   plt.show()
   if n==0:
       break
show_data(test, IMAGE_SIZE)
# Turn image of (C, H, W) into (B, C, H, W) to pass into the model
# Take the index of the highest probability from the output tensor and grab the corresponding classification
print("AI's Prediction: " + labels[torch.argmax(model(test[0].view(-1, 1, 16, 16)), 1)])
```

I get an error because of the show_data function. If I change the bottom `data_sample[0]` to `data_sample[1]` and don't change the top one, It doesn't show an error but the wrong label.

Here is how I created my dataset:

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
IMAGE_SIZE = 16
# Load the dataset using the ImageFolder class
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Dataset',
                              transforms.Compose([
                                  transforms.Resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)),
                                  transforms.ToTensor(),
                                  transforms.Grayscale()]))

train_dataset = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
dataset_train, dataset_val = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])
labels = ["5","10","20","30","40","50","75","100","150","200"]

for batch in train_dataset:
   print(batch)
   break
```

Can you please help me fix this? Thank you so much.

I tried to change both of the indexes to `1`, and I got this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. complete traceback required.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.